# how to send ajax put request from jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, put

I want to write back to my google spreadsheet after authorizing user. Authorizing is complete. But, to write back to spreadsheet, I have send PUT request as stated [here](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#UpdatingCells). It is from iGoogle Gadget.

My XML element is :

```
var cellUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key + "/od6/private/full/R2C2";
var XMLData = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006'>" + 
                "<id>" + cellUrl + "</id><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='" + cellUrl + "'/>" + 
                "<gs:cell row='2' col='2' inputValue='300'/>" + 
            "</entry>";
```

I am sending AJAX request as :

```
$.ajax({
                url: cellUrl,
                type: "PUT",
                contentType: 'application/atom+xml',
                processData: false,
                data: XMLData,
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }, success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                    alert("Succeeded");
                }
            });
```

Still, it is not writing back and not showing any alert as well ! What is problem ?

Should I use POST for writing back ? How do I do that ?

I have hidden cellURL key for security. And it is similar to the key in my spreadsheet url.

Comment: Smells like a StackOverflow.com question...

Comment: Can you check where the request is actually getting submitted? You can use firebug/developer tools for this.

Comment: Which browser are you using? As per the jquery documentation the `PUT` and `DELETE` request types are not supported by all the browsers. Can you check where `POST` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion

- check 'key' resourceID should escape
- if still not working, try put everything in  and add  and use click event. For ajax, use iframe.
- try $.ajax({... , data:$(XMLData), ...});

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this to see whether there is an error:

```
$.ajax({
        url: cellUrl,
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: 'application/atom+xml',
        processData: false,
        data: XMLData
    }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert(errorThrown);
    }, success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
       alert("Succeeded");
    }

);
```

Comment: I have added dataType : "xml" & your code as well but it shows nothing :( ! No alert there !

Comment: are you sure the $.ajax request is being executed? can you put an alert("Working!!"); just before the ajax request and confirm? are you using FF/Firebug or Chrome so that you can debug it?

Comment: Ok ! I have removed that error as well. Now it shows "Succeeded". But, it hasn't written back the data !

Comment: Try alert(data + "  ,  " + textStatus "  , " +  XMLHttpRequest); in the success function to see if that gives you any insight into why it doesn't work...